# Check if a string is empty or blank

Tags: rust

What's the proper way to check if a string is empty or blank for a) &str b) String? I used to do it by `"aaa".len() == 0`, but there should another way as my gut tells me?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Both `&str` and `String` have a method called `is_empty`:

- Documentation for [&str::is_empty](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.is_empty)
- Documentation for [String::is_empty](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/collections/string/struct.String.html#method.is_empty)

This is how they are used:

```
assert_eq!("".is_empty(), true); // a)
assert_eq!(String::new().is_empty(), true); // b)
```

Comment: The "".to_string() version is an unnecessary String allocation.

Comment: @pyrho I believe that the intention was to show that both `&str` and `String` have the `is_empty()` method.

Comment: I guessed so, I was just pointing out that it was bad practice (:

Comment: FYI, `"".to_string()` does not cause an allocation (at least in current Rust).  It translates to a `RawVec::with_capacity(0)`, which does not allocate, as per Rust source code https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/raw_vec.rs.html#94-96.

Answer (score 41):

Empty or whitespace only string can be checked with:

```
s.trim().is_empty()
```

where `trim()` returns a slice with whitespace characters removed from beginning and end of the string (https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim).

Comment: I expected this would not perform well, but then I looked at the source. Good answer!

Answer (score 5):

Others have responded that `Collection.is_empty` can be used to know if a string is empty, but assuming by "is blank" you mean "is composed only of whitespace" then you want [`UnicodeStrSlice.is_whitespace()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/str/trait.UnicodeStrSlice.html#tymethod.is_whitespace), which will be true for both empty strings and strings composed solely of characters with the `White_Space` unicode property set.

Only string slices implement `UnicodeStrSlice`, so you'll have to use [`.as_slice()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/str/trait.Str.html#tymethod.as_slice) if you're starting from a `String`.

tl;dr: `s.is_whitespace()` if `s: &str`, `s.as_slice().is_whitespace()` if `s: String`

Comment: It seems to be a unstable external crate, is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Found in the doc :

```
impl Collection for String
    fn len(&self) -> uint
    fn is_empty(&self) -> bool
```

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp what else ?

Comment: what about what else?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Oh I misread you, sorry. as length can't be negative, it returns an unsigned int

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: In the language, unit is written `()`, not literally `unit`.

Comment: @FrancisGagné, unit is written as unit, the value of unit is ().

Comment: why did you omit { }?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: Actually, both the type and the value are written `()`.